# why is draggable not working on parent when greedy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, droppable, greedy

I added the option greedy:true on my droppable but after dragging an element into a child, the parent is not responding. I think is a problem with jqueryui.

To reproduce drop an element into the child and then try to drop another element directly into the parent (without passing over the child first), the parent wont be border:green (the over function is not being called)

[** **jsFiddle** **](http://jsfiddle.net/frZzw/10/)

```
$("#right, #right *").droppable({
    greedy:true,
    tolerance:"pointer",
    cursor:"pointer",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if ($(this).attr("id")!="right") $(this).css("height","auto");
        $(this).css("border","3px solid blue");
        $("<div>appended</div>").appendTo(this);
    },
    over: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css("border","3px solid green"); //this is failing in the parent
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css("border","3px solid blue");
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks like it's working as supposed to. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: if you drop one element into the child and then try to drop another element into the parent dragging directly into it, the parent is suposed to be border:green which its not happening. I've tested on ie11 and Chrome30.

Comment: So here is what I did in your jFiddle. I dragged the very first "drag me!" into the "insert here!" box, and it got stuck after its border changed to green. Also, I dragged the same "drag me!" box into the parent of the "insert here!" box, which changed the border to green. So, it worked right?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Well, it's not working for me.

Comment: I tested on Chrome 30.0.1599.69, FF15, and Safari 6.0.5. They all worked fine.